# Como mudar o tema do aplicativo no Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, mobile, framework

Estou utilizando o Ionic 4 e estou com dificuldades para mudar o tema para dark.

No ionic 3, eu apenas ia no documento **variables.scss** e fazia a mudança:

```
de
@import "ionic.theme.default"; 
para
@import "ionic.theme.dark";
```

Agora, quando eu entro no documento **variables.scss** não tem mais o import do "ionic.theme". Como faço para mudar o tema do meu aplicativo no ionic 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele trabalha com componentização, exemplo:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.dark.scss'],
})
```

Se você usa [materials](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming):

```
function changeTheme(themeName) {
  document.getElementById('themeAsset').href = `/path/to/my/${themeName}.css`;
}
```